# Oracle like statement not using correct index

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

Oracle database.

I've got the following segment of SQL that's performing a full table scan on PROVIDER P1 table. I believe this is because it's dynamically building a like clause as you can see on line XXX.

I've got an index on PROVIDER.TERMINAL_NUMBER and the following SQL snippet does use the correct index.

```
select * from providers where terminal_number like '1234%'
```

so why does the following not hit that index?

```
SELECT P1.PROVIDER_NUMBER, P1.TERMINAL_NUMBER, PC."ORDER" FROM PROVIDERS P1
  INNER JOIN PROVIDER_CONFIG PC
         ON PC.PROVIDER_NUMBER = P1.PROVIDER_NUMBER
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT E2.* FROM EQUIPMENT E1
    INNER JOIN EQUIPMENT E2
            ON E1.MERCHANT_NUMBER = E2.MERCHANT_NUMBER
  WHERE E1.TERMINAL_NUMBER = 'SA323F'
  AND E1.STATUS IN (0, 9)
  AND E2.STATUS IN (0, 9)
  XXX 
  AND P1.TERMINAL_NUMBER LIKE SUBSTR(E2.TERMINAL_NUMBER, 0, length(E2.TERMINAL_NUMBER) - 1) || '%'
)
ORDER BY PC."ORDER" DESC
```

Comment: _"I believe this is because it's dynamically building a like clause"_ - this is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ...

```
 select * from providers where terminal_number like '1234%'
```

... the Optimiser knows all the fitting numbers start with a fixed prefix and so will be co-located in the index. Hence reading the index is likely to be very efficient.

But here there is no such knowledge ...

```
P1.TERMINAL_NUMBER LIKE SUBSTR(E2.TERMINAL_NUMBER, 0, length(E2.TERMINAL_NUMBER) - 1) || '%'
```

There can be any number of different prefixes from `E2.TERMINAL_NUMBER` and the query will be returning records from all over the `PROVIDERS` table. So indexed reads will be highly inefficient, and a blunt approach of full scans is the right option.

It may be possible to rewrite the query so it works more efficiently - for instance you would want a Fast Full Index Scan rather than a Full Table Scan. But without knowing your data and business rules we're not really in a position to help, especially when dynamic query generation is involved.

One thing which might improve performance would be to replace the WHERE EXISTS with a WHERE IN...

```
SELECT P1.PROVIDER_NUMBER, P1.TERMINAL_NUMBER, PC."ORDER" FROM PROVIDERS P1
  INNER JOIN PROVIDER_CONFIG PC
         ON PC.PROVIDER_NUMBER = P1.PROVIDER_NUMBER
WHERE substr(P1.TERMINAL_NUMBER, 1, 5) IN  (
  SELECT SUBSTR(E2.TERMINAL_NUMBER, 1, 5)
    FROM EQUIPMENT E1
    INNER JOIN EQUIPMENT E2
            ON E1.MERCHANT_NUMBER = E2.MERCHANT_NUMBER
  WHERE E1.TERMINAL_NUMBER = 'SA323F'
  AND E1.STATUS IN (0, 9)
  AND E2.STATUS IN (0, 9)
)
ORDER BY PC."ORDER" DESC
```

This would work if the length of the terminal number is constant. Only you know your data, so only you can tell whether it will fly.

Comment: `SELECT null` won't make the query any bit faster compared to `SELECT e2.*` that is a performance myth that was never true for Oracle (and many other DBMS)

Answer (score 0):

If this query does not use an index:

```
select *
from providers
where terminal_number like '1234%'
```

Then presumably `terminal_number` is numeric and not a string.  The type conversion prevents the use of the index.

If you want to use an index, then convert the value to a string and use a string index:

```
create index idx_providers_terminal_number_str on providers(cast(terminal_number as varchar2(255)));
```

Then write the query as:

```
select *
from providers
where cast(terminal_number as varchar2(255)) like '1234%'
```